# Onejar-maven-plugin error

Tags: java, maven

I copied to my pom.xml file code from [this page](http://onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/mavensite/usage.html), and after I type in console `mvn package` it shows me this kind of error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.dstovall:onejar-maven-plugin:1.4.4:one-jar (default) on project my-project:
Execution default of goal org.dstovall:onejar-maven-plugin:1.4.4:one-jar failed: basedir c:\Users\Dawid\Deskt
op\Pracbaza\my-project\target\dllextract does not exist -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Should I create this `c:\Users\Dawid\Deskt
    op\Pracbaza\my-project\target\dllextract` folder?

Comment: You probably have a line return in your pom file in the middle of the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the configuration you copied has

```
<fileSet>
   <directory>${project.build.directory}/dllextract</directory>
    <includes>
        <include>test.dll</include>
    </includes>
 </fileSet>
```

so it tries to goto this directory and put this file inside your jar, remove entire `<binlib>` from your `pom.xml`